# Why aren't my objects showing in object mode

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, object-mode

I'm having trouble viewing my objects in the object mode, even when I click on them in the menu, I couldn't find them in the canvas. The only object visible is a spot light, could you help me see what's wrong? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the top left of your *3D Viewport* you can see **(Local)** behind the words *User Perspective*. You switch to *Local View* with <kbd>Numpad /</kbd> and it means that you restrict the view to objects that are selected in this moment, all others will be invisible. You can also see in the next line that the object "Cube" is selected - but in the *Outliner* you can see it is set to be invisible in the viewport, that's why there is nothing to see in local view, not even the cube.

[image: local view]

Comment: Thank you so much! It's solved.

Comment: @Deee Please take your time to read this: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). No matter which answer you choose, but please indicate to others that there is a solution to this question.

Answer (score 0):

As you see at the top left of your 3D view, you are in *Local* view, which means that you have (accidentally?) pressed <kbd>/</kbd> which isolates the selected object(s) (here the camera), press <kbd>/</kbd> again to display all the objects:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I pressed / and it's solved.